# How to rearrange several divs on window resize - jQuery or CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries, window-resize

I would like to ask for some advice or idea how to change the position of several `div`s when the window is resized (for example on a mobile device).

The problem is that I cannot create one `div` for a desktop user, copy the same `div` for a mobile user and then do `display:none` for one of those depending on the window size because the `div`s have to have unique `id`.

So I need to do it either with CSS or jQuery. Any ideas will be appreciated. This is what I need:
[image]

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bradg/36fh7hn3/2/)

Thank you!

Comment: What about http://cssmediaqueries.com/ ?

Comment: Would be logical to wrap `a1` and `b1` in the same div and `a2` and `b2` in another div, that will achieve your desired effect without the need of JS

Comment: At the end of your design, are the parent `<div>`s going to be visible (some border, background, box-shadow etc.) or are you going to have the current borders removed and make them invisible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use media queries for that

```
@media (max-width:768px){
 .b, .a {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    height: auto;
 }
}
```

JS

```
 var flag =true;
 $( window ).resize(function() {

 if($(this).width() <= 768){

 if(flag){

   var b1 = $('.b1').clone();
   var a2= $('.a2').clone();
   $('.a').find('.a2').remove();
   $('.b').find('.b1').remove();
   $('.a').append(b1);
   $('.b').prepend(a2)
   flag= false;
  }

 }else{
 if(!flag){

  var b1 = $('.b1').clone();
  var a2= $('.a2').clone();
  $('.a').find('.b1').remove();
  $('.b').find('.a2').remove();
  $('.a').append(a2);
  $('.b').prepend(b1)
  flag= true;
 }

 }
});
```

I updated your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/36fh7hn3/5/

Comment: This does not change the order of inner divs :(

Comment: @user3132858 Ok, great! remember to check the last version https://jsfiddle.net/36fh7hn3/5/

Comment: Tested your solution, works great! Thank you for spending some time to help out!

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox with the 'order' property and media queries.

Or this could possibly be achieved using the 'float' property and media queries depending upon your use case.